# Accessing one code using another code on RobotDyn Uno+WiFi board

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial

Ok so I've been trying to do this for quite some time now. Still couldn't get it to work. I am trying to read a ESP8266 WiFi program from a normal Arduino Uno program. I've seen some people do this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
```

Then

```
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3);
```

Let me see a working example of this?

Thanks for everything.

Comment: it is an additional Serial interface called `esp8266`. You can print to it and read from it by Stream functions. What else? https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/

Comment: Thanks, so from what I perceive, Stream is a library? If it is, I would go include it.

Comment: Stream is a common class from which Serial, SoftwareSerial and similar are derived

Comment: You can't 'access code'. You can write sketches to communicate for example over Serial or SoftwareSerial. You connect the pins of Serial interfaces RX to TX and let sketch in one MCU read or parse what the sketch in other MCU sent over Serial with print or write.

Comment: I am using this board: 

[Link I bought the board from](https://robotdyn.com/uno-wifi-r3-atmega328p-esp8266-32mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html)

The WiFi shield is integrated with the board, so I think no need to connect the PINs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 'access code'. You can write sketches to communicate for example over Serial or SoftwareSerial. You connect the pins of Serial interfaces RX to TX and let sketch in one MCU read or parse what the sketch in other MCU sent over Serial with print or write.

The onboard connection on Uno+WiFi board is over Serial. So you can't use USB and connection to esp8266 at the same time. But you could use SoftwareSerial like other use it with esp8266, if you connect some pins (for example 6 and 7) of Uno headers to Serial of esp8266 which is accessible on the esp8266 header on the board.

[image]

Comment: So in order to communicate because Arduino sketch and the ESP8266 sketch, I must 
[1] connect the TX and RX of Arduino to RX and TX of ESP8266
[2] use serial stream class to send and receive data between them
Am I correct?

Comment: RS and TX of esp8266 and Atmega are connected on board, if you set it on DIP switches. but then the connection to computer is out. all tutorials on Internet show you how to use SoftwareSerial to connect to esp8266 and have Serial connection over USB to computer. and you can achieve this SoftwareSerial connection with this board too. by wiring selected Atmega SoftwareSerial pins to RX and TX of esp8266 and setting the DIP switches to connect Serial of Atmega to computer over USB

Comment: So does it mean, if I use SoftwareSerial, I must use the external connection as it is required by the SoftwareSerial library and it does not occupy the physical USB serial port so I can still connect the board to computer?

If I don't want to use SoftwareSerial (and thus no need external wiring), what is the option I have to communicate between ESP8266 and Arduino sketches?

Comment: Switches 1 and 2 connect Atmega to esp8266. I recommend you to use this SoftwareSerial connection for developing the sketch. otherwise you would have hard time always switching the DIP switches for upload of sketch and you could not have debug prints in Serial Monitor.

Comment: A BIG thank you for your kind assistance and advice. I now have better understanding on how should I proceed.

Comment: a small note: the Mega+WiFi has it better. Atmega 2560 on board has more Serials so Serial3 can be connected to esp8266 and Serial to USB as usual

Comment: One more question. To upload sketch to ESP8266, I need to turn on DIP switch 5,6,7. To upload sketch to Atmega, I need to turn on DIP switch 3,4. So it means I still need to switch the DIP switches when I upload. Just in case I want to get rid of external wiring, I can turn on DIP switch 1,2? In the table it says Mega328+ESP8266 if 1,2 is ON, I guess it means Mega328 and ESP8266 can communicate if DIP is 1,2?

Comment: I'll take note on your advice on using Atmega2560 on board for my next project.

Comment: a good trick is uploading to esp8266 over WiFi with ArduinoOTA library. the you need to switch USB to esp8266 only if the OTA upload doesn't success

Comment: Thanks for the ArduinoOTA tips. I am running out of time for current project. Will definitely try it out on my next project. THANK YOU!!! You made my day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84229/discussion-between-w-adrian-and-juraj).